# URL params when using select_tag in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I use options_from_collection_for_select.

The attribute is called category, and has an associated id. I would love to see params in the URL like this : &category=32

However, they now look like &category=32 with an additional &multiselect_select_category=32

The full URL I am getting is:

```
<url>/advanced_search_res?utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=test&category=29&category=32&category=34&category=35&multiselect_select_category=29&multiselect_select_category=32&multiselect_select_category=34&multiselect_select_category=35
```

The call within the form is:
    <%=select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(@category,"id" , "name"),:multiple => true, :class=>"bbFormSelect",:id=>"select_category", :name => "category" %>

any thoughts on how to do this? thank you!

===============

update: how the html of the select tag looks like

```
<select class="bbFormSelect" id="select_category" multiple="multiple" name="category[]" style="display: none; ">
<option value="1">Aerospace &amp; Defense</option>
<option value="25">Leisure</option>
<option value="29">Nonprofit Institutions</option>
<option value="32">Retail</option>
...
<button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 225px; "><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>1 selected</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that you're providing the name attribute explicitly as an html attribute when the syntax is for select_tag is:

```
select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})
```

The name is set by the first parameter, so it's already set to "category".

Could you provide the html source that is generated by rails in the form?